# Pandas convert multi index header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with the following format:

```
        price                cost              
   id   mean   max    min    mean   max    min  
    0     1     1      1       1     2      3
    1     2     2      2       1     2      3
    2     3     3      3       1     2      3
```

I would like to change it to the following:

```
   id      mean   max    min    type
    0       1     1      1     price    
    1       2     2      2     price  
    2       3     3      3     price
    0       1     1      1     cost       
    1       2     2      2     cost   
    2       3     3      3     cost
```

Comment: Please accept one of our answers or describe how they do not answer your specific question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

try with `stack()` method,`drop()` method, `reset_index()` method and `rename()` method:

```
df=(df.stack(0)
 .drop('id',1)
 .reset_index()
 .rename(columns={'level_0':'id','level_1':'type'}))
```

Output of `df`:

```
    id  type    max     mean    min
0   0   cost    2       1       1
1   0   price   1       1       3
2   1   cost    2       1       2
3   1   price   2       2       3
4   2   cost    2       1       3
5   2   price   3       3       3
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `rename_axis` + `stack` and follow with `sort_values`

```
out = df.rename_axis(['type',None],axis=1).stack(0).reset_index().sort_values('type')
Out[294]: 
   id   type  max  mean  min
0   0   cost    2     1    3
2   1   cost    2     1    3
4   2   cost    2     1    3
1   0  price    1     1    1
3   1  price    2     2    2
5   2  price    3     3    3
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the difference between the long- and short-form of a table.

You can use `.stack()`, `.reset_index()`, and `.rename()` to convert your desired format.

```py
df.stack(0).reset_index(1).rename(columns={'level_1': 'type'})
```

Here's an [awesome article](https://medium.com/swlh/reshaping-in-pandas-with-stack-and-unstack-functions-bb169f64467d) with nice visualizations describing how stack and unstack works.

And here's the result step by step:

```py
>>> df
  price         cost        
   mean max min mean max min
0     1   1   1    1   2   3
1     2   2   2    1   2   3
2     3   3   3    1   2   3
```

```py
>>> df.stack(level=0)
         max  mean  min
0 cost     2     1    3
  price    1     1    1
1 cost     2     1    3
  price    2     2    2
2 cost     2     1    3
  price    3     3    3
```

```py
>>> df.stack(level=0).reset_index(level=1)
  level_1  max  mean  min
0    cost    2     1    3
0   price    1     1    1
1    cost    2     1    3
1   price    2     2    2
2    cost    2     1    3
2   price    3     3    3
```

```py
>>> df.stack(level=0).reset_index(level=1).rename(columns={'level_1': 'type'})
     type max  mean  min
0   cost    2     1    3
0  price    1     1    1
1   cost    2     1    3
1  price    2     2    2
2   cost    2     1    3
2  price    3     3    3
```

If you need to maintain the id column (it is not a useless auto-incrementing column), you can add an extra `set_index` and `reset_index` to keep that column:

```py
>>> df.set_index('id').stack(0).reset_index(1) \
    .rename(columns={'level_1': 'type'}).reset_index()
   id   type  max  mean  min
0   0   cost    2     1    3
1   0  price    1     1    1
2   1   cost    2     1    3
3   1  price    2     2    2
4   2   cost    2     1    3
5   2  price    3     3    3
```